# Set a value in a separate workbook, and reverts back to old value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a handful of values from one workbook to the other. The first value I am setting matches with a dropdown on the other workbook, which then opens a few other fields depending on which input you choose. After the code runs, it looks like it changes to the value I want for a second or two, then it goes back to the original dropdown value. When I comment out the for each loop after entering the first value, it enters the value that I want, but when I activate the loop, the first value goes back to its original state. I've tried a Application.Wait for 3 seconds, I've tried ScreenUpdating = TRUE, I've tried saving the file after entering the first value but nothing works. When I do the wait for 3 seconds, everything still seems to update all at once, even though the Application.Wait occurs after entering the first value. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Rarorc()
Dim cs As Workbook
Dim calcs As Worksheet
Dim csrrvalrng As Range
Dim i
Dim rr As Workbook
Dim InvFin As Worksheet
Dim csref As String
Dim csval As Variant
Dim rrcell As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set cs = ThisWorkbook
Set calcs = cs.Worksheets("Calculations")
Set csrrvalrng = calcs.Range("RARORC_Table[Field Value]")
Set rr = Workbooks.Open("V:\AarealUSA\Common\ACC Templates\RARORC.xlsm")
Set InvFin = rr.Worksheets("Investment Financing")
csref = calcs.Range("F2")
Set csval = calcs.Range("E2")
Set rrcell = InvFin.Range("D102")

rrcell.Value = csval
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\mhenry\Desktop\Capital Simulation\rr.xlsm"
Application.Wait "00:00:03"
For Each i In csrrvalrng
    csval = i
    csref = i.Offset(0, 1)
    Set rrcell = InvFin.Range(csref)
    rrcell.Value = csval
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Let's say the name of your currently open workbook (with this macro) is named "C:\Temp\CoolCalculations.xlsm". The variable `cs` is initialized to work with this workbook. When all your logic is completed, you execute `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\mhenry\Desktop\Capital Simulation\rr.xlsm"`. This means your original workbook in `C:\Temp\` is ***still*** called `CoolCalculations.xlsm` and **is not changed** because you saved all the changes to `rr.lxlsm`.  Basically, the code is doing exactly what you tell it to do. BTW... use `cs.SaveAs "C:\Users\..."` instead. It's much more clear.

Comment: A couple points of advice... you're using too many ranges - it's extremely hard to follow which range belongs to which worksheet and which workbook. You also declare `i` as `Variant` (implicitly), then go on to use it as a `Range`, which adds to the confusion as a best practice when using `i` as a variable is to declare it as an `Integer` or `Long`. Remove the `Application.Wait`, I can assure you that isn't doing anything to help you here.

Comment: `Set rrcell = InvFin.Range(csref)` - what do you think this line is doing?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that csref which is 1 column to the right of the value I want to enter which is a list of the cell referrences in the other sheet. I do this because these change all the time. I just added the Application.Wait to allow all the conditional formatting and other cells to change their data validation.

Comment: Also, thank you Peter, I was trying to save in a different location to break up the code so the changes would take effect.

Comment: My code transfers everything from my workbook to the other except for the first value. I can see that it changes for a second, but it changes right back.

Comment: Side note, but `For Each i In csrrvalrng` is not the way you want to write a `For Each` loop. `For Each rng` maybe. `i` is never used as a name for a `Range` object.